# Reducing amount of if/if code (C++)

Tags: c++, templates, if-statement

In my program I have to create an object, which looks like that:

`Library::Param1<Library::Param2>::Param3` (don't know how to name `Param`, types maybe?)
Similar to `std::vector<std::string>::iterator`.

So, these `Param`'s need to be changed by strings. For example:

```
if(param1 == "1_VALUE1")
{
    if(param2 == "2_VALUE1")
    {
        MyLib::1_VALUE1<MyLib::2_VALUE1>::Param3 obj;
        //Obj is used
    }
    //15+ similar if-statements, where only 2_VALUE1 changes
}
/*15+ similar if-statements, where only 1_VALUE1 changes,
  but the contents remain same (again 15+ if-statements)*/
```

*`using namespace MyLib;` is not neseccary.*

So, I need to reduce amount of those if-statements, but I do not know the way to do it. I think it could be done with templates, but I am not familiar with them, so, I guess, I would need a code sample.

Sorry for the bad english, if any more info is needed - let me know. Thank you.

--- EDIT: Library (CryptoPP) type-definitions:

Since errors are only on Param1, posting one variation of it:

```
//! CBC mode with ciphertext stealing
template <class CIPHER>
struct CBC_CTS_Mode : public CipherModeDocumentation
{
 typedef CipherModeFinalTemplate_CipherHolder<CPP_TYPENAME CIPHER::Encryption, CBC_CTS_Encryption> Encryption;
 typedef CipherModeFinalTemplate_CipherHolder<CPP_TYPENAME CIPHER::Decryption, CBC_CTS_Decryption> Decryption;
};
```

Comment: how are you going to use the objects? Do you do the same or a similar thing with them?

Comment: Exactly same usage for all of them.

Comment: so they all have a method (let's say it's called foo())? Is this a virtual method and do all those types inherit from the same abstract base class?

Comment: Could you please be more specific about where these `if`s are? Is this a function? Or?

Comment: I create them, and pass into a library function as parameters.

Comment: About inheritance: I will look at library`s source code. About if's: They are in my created class method (function).

Comment: how does the string changes actually? If there is a pattern, then you may use loop variables and append those variables into your strings and use nested loop instead of multiple ifs. And if there is no pattern, you may use loop-up tables and use a loop variable to index the LUT.

Comment: There is no pattern. Strings come from GUI, where user has a choice of 20+ of these. Haven't actually understood what you meant.

Comment: Inheritance: Param1 inherits one struct; Param2 inherits two classes (first is different for each possibility, second is the same);

Comment: I would not like to dig into library's inner things, just use the API provided.

Comment: Does anyone know if this is possible using `boost::mpl` with possibly a `typedef boost::mpl::string<'Param2'> string_name` in each `Param` class? Then a `mpl::map` of the different types.  You would need a method that expanded the `mpl::map` into the if comparisons for you...this is the part I'm not sure is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Mark B that a factory would be nice, but I'm not sure if this is possible if you do not have a base class that all these types inherit from. If I understand the problem correcty, you have 15 types for Value 1 and 15 types for Value2 which leads to  15*15 if-statements. You can reduce them to 2*15 with the following approach: (untested)

---EDIT1: changed order of methods ---

template 
    void level2()
    {
      typename T1_T2::Param3 obj;
      doSomething(obj);
    }

```
template <template<class> class T1>
void level1(std::string param2)
{
 if (param2 == "2_VALUE1")
   level2<T1<MyLib::2_Value1> >();
 if (param2 == "2_VALUE1")
   level2<T1<MyLib::2_Value2> >();
 ...
}


void level0(std::string param1, std::string param2)
{
 if (param1 == "1_VALUE1")
   level1<MyLib::1_Value1>(param2);
 if (param2 == "1_VALUE2")
   level1<MyLib::1_Value2>(param2);
 ...
}
```

--- EDIT2 ---

To help you figure out why you can't compile, you can start with this sample code (compiles on Visual Studio 2008):

```
void doSomething(int x)
{
}

struct Type2_1 {};

template <class T2>
struct Type1_1
{
    typedef int Param3;
};

template <class T2>
struct Type1_2
{
    typedef int Param3;
};

template <template<class> class T1>
void level1(std::string param2)
{
 if (param2 == "2_VALUE1")
   level2<T1<Type2_1> >();
}

void level0(std::string param1, std::string param2)
{
 if (param1 == "1_VALUE1")
   level1<Type1_1>(param2);
 if (param2 == "1_VALUE2")
   level1<Type1_2>(param2);
}

template <class T1_T2>
void level2()
{
  typename T1_T2::Param3 obj;
  doSomething(obj);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  level0("1_VALUE1", "2_VALUE1");
  return 0;
}
```

Please note that "doSomething()" should be whatever you want MyLib to do with your obj; Returning obj from level0/1/2 won't work without a base class.

Comment: In level0 it MinGW complains about: `missing template arguments before '>' token`. Could you remake the level2 function so it returns the object? (What's the return value then?, What variable I should create to store it, if needed?).

Comment: Excuse me, I meant return type.

Comment: two thoughts: 1.) you might want to define level2 before level1 and level1 before level0. 2.) what are the real names of your types? I hope it's not 1_ValueX? This would not be valid.

Comment: Did not understood what you meant. Maybe, I would not even need to create a variable to store the `obj`. I would just pass the return value right to the library's function (see my comment to Mark B answer). All of possible string values would be covered by if`s, if you were asking that.

Comment: @EdgeLuxe: There is no practical solution to return an object from the `level[0-2]` functions. The functions create 15*15 (225) different, unrelated, types of objects, and a function in C++ can only return objects of a single type. `Boost::Variant` or `Boost::Any` might look promising at first, but then you get the question 'what type is actually stored here' when you need to access the variable.

Comment: Well, I have figured out what class library accepts as parameter. (Strange things happen, I didn't see it in inheritance, maybe I was looking for it elsewhere). Now, only thing I need is to fix the syntax.

Comment: @EdgeLuxe: Please see my edits. I changed my code and added a working sample.

Comment: Oh, well, okay. I will use obj without returning. EDIT2 code compiles fine (just warns about uninitialized obj). But my code doesn't. I get the same error in level0 function. Seems to be that library's `Type1_[1-2]` somehow requires the argument to be passed immediately. Any other ideas? Or what mine code should I add to the question?

Comment: maybe you can post the typedefinitions?

Comment: Added. Anything else? Thanks.

Comment: @EdgeLuxe: Thanks for the edit. If your types are defined like this, you should be able to use CBC_CTS_Mode insteaf of Type1_[1-2] and replace my "Param3" by Encryption/Decryption. the template definition of level1 states that you must not include the template argument when "calling" level1, so this should not be the problem. Please try to convert the working sample step by step to your types and you should find out where exactly the difference is.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have called function and a parameter with a same name (where was my attention?). So, everything is fixed now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the *type* dynamically using `if` statements like that, which isn't well supported by C++, consider using something like a factory pattern instead.

Basically you set up a hierarchy of classes that have virtual methods that implement what you're trying to do in the `if` cases. You then make a function that creates the appropriate child class from a set of strings, and then you call `go` or whatever on the created instance.

Comment: Could you please give an example? (Link to appropriate example maybe). As I said in comments, "I create them, and pass into a library function as parameters". Like `MyLib::foo(obj);`